# Squid: how to enable verification for SSL self-signed certificates

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, squid, openssl, certificate-authority

I'm using **Squid 3.4.8** as a **reverse proxy** which is forwarding request to a specific server. The communication between Squid and the server is in HTTPS.

The certificate used by the server is **self-signed**, meaning that I created a **CA certificate** with which I signed the server certificate.

I would like to properly verify the server certificate by using my CA certificate (instead of setting sslproxy_flags to DONT_VERIFY_PEER, which is not safe). How can I configure Squid to do that?

I suppose I have to set sslproxy_flags to NO_DEFAULT_CA and then use some particular acl to allow all SSL certificates issued by my CA, but after reading the documentation I'm a bit confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround for this problem.
Instead of configuring Squid I added the CA certificate to the list of trusted CA certificates system-wide.

I followed the instructions here http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/others.shtml